# What makes a typescript module, a typescript module? Toastr example

Tags: node.js, typescript, toastr

I was just using `toastrjs` for a few notifications, and I ran into this little problem. Ideally, when you import a library in nodejs, you have to make an `import` statement, like so:

```
import http = require("http");
```

However, when I tried this with `toastr`, I get an error, even after including the reference path. So, something like this:

```
///<reference path='toastr.d.ts' />
import toastr = require("./toastr");
```

I get this error:

```
error TS2071: Unable to resolve external module '"./toastr.js"'.
error TS2072: Module cannot be aliased to a non-module type.
```

How is `toastr` different from a regular node module like `http`?

### Update 1

I tried to do the same thing with `jQuery` but I have the same problems, does this mean that this does not work with frameworks that are designed to be client-side?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the following declare definition would create a module you can import via amd/commonjs:

```
declare module "jquery"{
    export var jQuery: JQueryStatic;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
import jquery = require("jquery");
```

You can see such definitions in this underscore definition: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/underscore/underscore.d.ts#L2853

or node.d.ts : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts#L203

However not all files on DT have this definition. As it is simple enough to add on your own and you are free to name these modules whatever you want (in your AMD configuration http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AGQpv0MKsA )

Comment: This doesn't appear to help in the case of Toastr in a browser. I had to resort to including toastr.js directly in my main page.